# Export docx file in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some docx file at server with some specific place and i just want to download them using php.but we can't redirect them at given places because there is actual client documents are stored

I tried to google but didn't get much appropriate solution for that

Current code :

```
    function  users_export_resume($id){

        $filename=base_url()."user_info/".$id."/resume.docx";
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Resume.docx"); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");  
        readfile($filepath);
    }
```

Any suggestions ? 
is there anything wrong ?
Please take me out
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why don't you just do a redirect as the result `header('Location: '.$newURL);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: I don't believe like need to redirect at that place where i am store my client document so please give me another alternative because of that even i need also file name must be need to change instead of same file name given that's need for security purpose

Comment: Its not redirect issue so please remove your comment like its duplicate of redirect

Comment: Mods will remove it if it's not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I think error is:

1. you use undefined variable `$filepath`
2. variable `$filename` must contain path to file, not link.

So, your code must be:

```
define('WWW_ROOT', '/var/www/your_site_address'); // put it into C:\www\etc on Windows

function  users_export_resume($id){
    $filename=WWW_ROOT."/user_info/".$id."/resume.docx";
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");;
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Resume.docx"); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");  
    readfile($filename);
}
```

and in this case your code work well for me.

I hope it will help.

**EDIT 1:**

I fixed code for multi-OS issue

Comment: Nope it will not work if i will consider like my app must need to compatible with linux as well as microsoft than it will create issue
I can't give static path for that

Comment: i just want to know is there anything wrong with header because i can't get exact solution for that please help me if you get better solution with dynamic path instead of static path

Comment: @AnkitDoshi your code contain 2 errors. I fixed it in my example. All headers is correct. Also i added constant for linux and windows.

Comment: @Thanks for reply now download file size is same as actual file size but still whenever i am trying to export there is give me error please refer below url
http://postimg.org/image/72kc0ywwr/

Comment: @AnkitDoshi, hmm very interesting. Try add `error_reporting(0);` into begin on your PHP file. Probably some external characters get to output...

Comment: @AnkitDoshi save the file instead of opening it in word - then open the file in a text editor and check the top and bottom for php or anything else odd

Comment: @stepozer i am using Codeigniter and i put  error_reporting(E_ALL); in index.php for development  enviroment and application/config,php i put log_threshold =4 but there is nothing to show me which we can say or can think like its cause the error so anything else which i have to try

Comment: @Dagon check the top and bottom for php or anything else odd means i can't get it 
can you please explain some more info ?

Comment: when you click the link and the browser asks you what to do with the  file, save it, don't open it in word ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80532/discussion-between-ankit-doshi-and-dagon).

Comment: @AnkitDoshi I have same problem in window machine http://postimg.org/image/72kc0ywwr/ but when I tried into Linux machine its working correctly